# Quiz Program using a Text File

Tags: python, random

Am trying to create a quiz program in Python where the questions are stored in one txt file with the answers in another. The questions are set out in the text file as follows:

`Which one of these is a percussion instrument?
A. Trumpet
B. Euphonium
C. Viola
D. Glockenspiel`

The program pulls the questions out in random order and keeps score of the number of right answers.
I know how to open files, read from them and display the contents of the file on the screen, I even know now how to randomise the info in the file. However, as there are multiple lines involved AND another file to get the answer from, I have no idea where to start.
I would really appreciate any help you could offer me.
Feel free to ask questions if you need to clarify anything.

EDIT:
Ok, I have decided to change my idea a little, which might make it easier. Using a CSV file might be the better option. Here is what I have so far.

```
def Trivia():
score=0
myFile = open("farming.csv","r") # opens the CSV file and stores it in the array myFile
players = myFile.readlines() # reads the lines of the CSV file into the variable players
questionno=1
while questionno < 6:

    for p in players:
        data = p.split(",") #splits each cell of the CSV file into its parts
    questions = data[0]
    answera = data[1]
    answerb = data[2]
    answerc = data[3]
    CorrectAnswer = data[4]
    print("Question #",questionno)
    print(questions) #prints the question and the 3 answers
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(answera)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(answerb)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(answerc)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    answer = input("Answer? ") #asks the user for their answer
    time.sleep(1)
    print(".")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(".")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(".")

    if answer == CorrectAnswer: #checks if the answer is correct and prints approptiate responses
        print("That is the correct answer")
        score=score+1
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        print("That is not the correct answer")
        time.sleep(1)
    print("Your current score is", score)
    print("")
    questionno = questionno+1

myFile.close()
```

My problem now is that I don't know how to get to the next question in the quiz. Using this format it keeps asking the same question. Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to give more info about the intended format.  E.g., will questions be space separated?  Will the answer file contain only answers (e.g., each line contains a single character) or also a question identifier.

Comment: We're not a code-authoring service. Show us something at least.

Comment: Ok, I have decided to change my idea a little, which might make it easier. Using a CSV file might be the better option. Here is what I have so far. EDIT in original question.

Answer (score 0):

This question is two-fold: what to save, and how to save. Let's answer "how" first.

Seems like what you need is [serialization](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization), which is a fancy way of saying "saving data in a particular format". I would learn about [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) or [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html). This will allow you to save and load **objects**, so you could for instance save a class that represents a question.

And about **what** you save and not how you save it, I guess each answer should be saved along with a number of a question, then you can link between them - sort of like [foreign keys in a DB](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly 100 percent sure as yet I haven't run the program myself to check. But I think it could be the "While" module. It says while questionno is under six,  do that question, and so when you add 1 to questionno it is still under 6 running the program over again. Change it too this

If questionno == 1:
.....
.....
.....

## for next question in the quiz you'll need to just start it with

If questionno == 2:
.....
.....
.....

## now write the 2nd quiz

Comment: This is attacking the problem with a hammer. Op, the for-in syntax might be your best bet `for a in range(5):
    print(a)`